# How to create type with one or more keys with string value whilst allowing other fields of any type?

Tags: typescript

I am making a combobox component which takes two parameters:

1. `options`: a series of objects to select from
2. `displaytextKeyname`: a string which represents the name of a key to look at within each `option` which contains a string to display as the name

Here is a simplified example of this in use:

```js
type ComboboxProps<T> = {
    options: T[];
    displaytextKeyname: string;
}

const Combobox = ({
    options,
    displaytextKeyname
}:ComboboxProps<unknown>) => {
    options.forEach(o => console.log(o[displayTextKeyname])
}
```

I am looking to make an object that would be suitable as type `T` above. The idea is this is designed in such a generic way that said field could be called `"description"`, `"longname"`, `"name"` or whatever. All that is required is that it is a string.

Currently I have attempted it in the following ways:

#### Approach 1 - require all string values

```js
type ComboboxOption = {
    [key: string]: string;
};

const foo: ComboboxOption = {
    a: "123",
    b: 456, // Type 'number' is not assignable to type string
};
```

#### Approach 2 - allow all values

```js
type ComboboxOption = {
    [key: string]: unknown;
};

const foo: ComboboxOption = {
    a: "123",
    b: 123,
};

// This allows objects which do not have at least one key with a string value
const bar: ComboboxOption = {
    b: 123,
};
```

#### Approach 3 - extend interface

```js
interface IComboboxOption {
    [key: string]: string;
}

//Interface 'IComboboxOptionExt' incorrectly extends interface 'IComboboxOption'.
  //'string' index signatures are incompatible.
    //Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'string'
interface IComboboxOptionExt extends IComboboxOption {
    [key: string | number | symbol]: unknown;
}
```

Is this beyond typescript's type system or am I just thinking about this entirely wrong?

Comment: is the series of objects you refer to, the `ComboboxOption` type? its not clear exactly what you mean plus a string... are you trying to define one mandatory property in this type and then any other propoerty type? would be good to see the consuming code

Comment: I have updated the question to include an example intended use case for clarity

Answer (score 1):

Yes, such a constraint is indeed too much for TypeScript types. A stand-alone type will not be able to express this behaviour.

But it is possible to achieve things like this with a generic function. This would be my approach:

```
function Combobox<
  Key extends string
>(key: Key, options: (Record<string, any> & Record<Key, string>)[]) {}
```

This will validate the passed array based on the constraint you specified.

```
Combobox("description", [{
  "description": "abc",
  a: 123
}])

Combobox("longname", [{
  "longname": "abc",
  a: 123
},{
  "longname": "efg",
  b: 456
}, {
  c: 123 // Error: '{ c: number; }' is not assignable to type 'Record<string, any> & Record<"longname", string>'
}])
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.0-beta#code/FDBmFcDsGMBcEsD2kAEBhRBbARo3APAHmBRQGkBTATxQv1gsgBMBnFF2AJ3kgHNgAfAAoA1tQBc5agBoUiAA4JkLSUIBKFaIk5NCHbn1kBDSFQEoAZCg1adhSlVn6evAQEoA2gF03KAN4AviAYOHiI+EIAREwULNDcikiQkbIefiQo0bHx8InIkZKRRtjQKRlGkgCMAEwAzMABPsFYuARRADbIvJBGmBQpKGkZkZ18PX0FmcWl0uVVdQ3S6aQjXeP9hRSgvGWk2JIALACsAGyL-hnQ8-WNbiBAA)

Answer (score 1):

While [@TobiasS.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72776832/5108796) is perfectly valid, it is possible to build a solution that is much closer to your initial description:

- using object destructuring, for a more React component-like signature (can be easily adapted  to @TobiasS.'s answer as well)
- using a standalone type, without necessarily applying it to a function (but only when used with a function can the generic be automatically inferred)

```
// Use a generic for the key instead of the array type
type ComboboxProps<Key extends string> = {
  displaytextKeyname: Key,
  // Constrain the array type using the key, like in @TobiasS.'s answer
  options: Array<Record<string, any> & { [k in Key]: string }>
}
```

Example using the type without a function:

```
// Using the type standalone,
// but we have to explicitly specify the generic type
const ComboboxObject: ComboboxProps<"hello"> = {
  displaytextKeyname: "hello",
  options: [{
    hello: "world",
    foo: 42
  }, {
    // @ts-expect-error
    hello: false // Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  },
  // @ts-expect-error
  {
    foo: "bar" // Type '{ foo: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Record<string, any> & { hello: string; }'. Property 'hello' is missing in type '{ foo: string; }' but required in type '{ hello: string; }'.
  }]
}
```

Example using the type in a function:

```
// Using the type for a function argument,
// the generic can be automatically inferred.
const Combobox = <Key extends string>({
  options,
  displaytextKeyname
}: ComboboxProps<Key>) => {
  options.forEach(o => console.log(o[displaytextKeyname]))
}

Combobox({
  displaytextKeyname: "description",
  options: [{
    "description": "abc",
    any: true
  }]
})

Combobox({
  displaytextKeyname: "longname",
  options: [{
    "longname": "abc",
    a: 123
  }, {
    // @ts-expect-error
    "longname": 4, // Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
    b: 456
  },
  // @ts-expect-error
  {
    c: 123 // Type '{ c: number; }' is not assignable to type 'Record<string, any> & { longname: string; }'. Property 'longname' is missing in type '{ c: number; }' but required in type '{ longname: string; }'.
  }]
})
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.0-beta#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gWwEZxQDwAoCc5gM4A8A0hCFBGsBAHYAmeUewWAltQOYB8UAvFAN4AoKFFos8YADYBDEFUokQ1aQggAuKIoA0wqLmAs41PBoCCWLLIIAlCAGM4WWgSasOWqNOohuAMgFQANoA1lBsmqQAuhqubOxQAL6cggmCgg7GwLCIKOgA8kgAVvbAGvDIqHCYOPgEAEQAFhCSknB13HxCImISMnIUwIrKqhqNza11OiL6hsYagV0iUE0tcKMA7o6StJO6IgBmcGtQACwATLoJHosiAPS3UAACwHgAtBSQdsDvFo57y+NjvtpJI8NB7lAACrgaAAchQcEkEC8sLCDGocCy0jweBY7GUSCRUGAcGJMKgsNiHFhADpLlMoBDnm8PiUfjgsLoblBDsc6khpFg6oyHtDIBT+DyjjFmHEANyJVHiKAYrE4vEEokksni2G2BxOFyy9yebx+AIrVoytzsBUJWlQbC4CBYUAUy1wJUMBDiXEcMLUHVwyW863yxVQJAAVyyWAgAEcoyw47QA0GJQDVmGOHbaZdIik0hkmNkKuheFBiKRyJQaPRGMauAAKRYzIx4Bk9KSyeSDUjDCApMo5SrVXCERScACUvG4rbABnbNMOWAAotI7A0m6SeNxi4iIDTWuxt4Eu31e0MVBBIlOp4XBOVclUW7pzz2BleRlA6rQIHg7FYBdZl2aZgPbeZuV-f9AJYcDqDqUZpCQOxQKWLwQA0Zgo0HEQEgLBJ70fEd0FfbpxG7foFH7a9RlaDgBzQts5iCKD6Pxa9EJ-ZDUIZERpA0ABGM4AGZ6QEf4mRed40E+b4XQ5f46nYxiNBODwITFOFqCjZAXS9FVMU8dUOMJaBtVAXUqXYPMlkjNSAFYADZ6V0KSWVktkFL+ERuTsITRJFKFyVhSV-JVXSkBdXM0UMtVcVMrVSUsuF9UcZxrI8DDzUlFTaIbG1cxpR0ahdN1YTy1QDJ9dV-XCFKM3CnS9KwGLo1jBMkxTNMGtCqBKvUArw3tOk8II+8gA)